# Unable to pull some image from jfrog artifactory with my containerd

Tags: containerd, jfrog-container-registry

I use containerd to launch docker image inside my K8S. I can't put proxy on my env and have no internet access on node vm.

I've install a JCR to be able to get docker image and provide it as a mirror.
This JCR has internet access.

When I look inside K8S I always see that it is not able to pull sandbox image "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1" it always goes on i/o timeout

I put  inside my Jcr several docker repote repository

docker-remote https://registry-1.docker.io/ 
k8s.gcr.io https://k8s.gcr.io/

and a virtual named docker

I put inside my containerd.toml

```
...
    [plugins.cri.registry]
      [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."*"]
          endpoint = ["https://docker.jcr.mydomain"]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://docker.jcr.mydomain"]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."k8s.gcr.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://docker.jcr.mydomain"]
```

And then it's able to pull the image but I really don't understand why it isn't able to pull this image with the "*" wild card. 
I cannot do this for all docker registry I need to find a solution to make the "*" work.

Another pb occured with the quay.io
For the docker registy quay.io I never manage to mirror it
Even if I put

```
...
    [plugins.cri.registry]
      [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."*"]
          endpoint = ["https://docker.jcr.mydomain"]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://docker.jcr.mydomain"]
        [plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."quai.io"]
          endpoint = ["https://docker.jcr.mydomain"]
```

and for this image `quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64` 
this is the result:

```
Pulling image "quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64"
  Warning  Failed     13s (x3 over 54s)  kubelet, 121a9964-9914-4548-b576-69d6ac1f88d8.k8s  Failed to pull image "quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64": failed to resolve reference "quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64": unexpected status code [manifests v0.11.0-amd64]: 403 Forbidden
  Warning  Failed     13s (x3 over 54s)  kubelet, 121a9964-9914-4548-b576-69d6ac1f88d8.k8s  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    1s (x3 over 54s)   kubelet, 121a9964-9914-4548-b576-69d6ac1f88d8.k8s  Back-off pulling image "quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64"
  Warning  Failed     1s (x3 over 54s)   kubelet, 121a9964-9914-4548-b576-69d6ac1f88d8.k8s  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason of why the "quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64" failed.
It's because it has a severe CVE inside this image and so on the Artifactory repository forbidde the download.
see https://quay.io/repository/coreos/flannel?tab=tags